# Khula: Is there an iddah period if no sex took place?

Tags: sharia, talaq, iddah

As my sister newly married last week, she wants *khula* from her husband. We registered a case in the Islamic shariah court due to his character not being good and some other issues. She had no sexual intercourse with him.

My question is, does she have a *Iddah period* even though no sexual intercourse took place?

Answer (score 2):

The following verse states that there is no iddah period if no sexual relations took place.

> O You who have believed, when you marry believing women and then
>   divorce them before you have touched them, **then there is not for you
>   any waiting period to count concerning them.** So provide for them and
>   give them a gracious release. (Qur'an 33:49)

Answer (score 0):

```
                                   In the name of Allah
```

In regard to your question that asked

> Is this girl has Iddah because no sexual intercourse..

I found almost precisely a same question as it has inquired “Is it ought to be kept the Iddah in case that there wasn’t any sexual intercourse?”

The presented response is that

> It is not necessary (to keep the Iddah in that case).  (Ayatollah
>   Sistani,  [www.sistani.org/persian](http://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/0971/)  )

**References:**

[www.sistani.org](http://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/0971/)

[portal.anhar.ir](http://portal.anhar.ir/contentview.php?export=print&ID=18954)